# UART/USART on XMEGA

Tags: uart, usart, atxmega

I am making a design and using the ATXMEGA128A4U ([datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-8387-8-and16-bit-avr-microcontroller-xmega-a4u_datasheet.pdf)) for the first time. I need to connect this MCU to two UART Modules (FTDI chip and Bluetooth module). I have two questions about this:

1) Can someone confirm that I can use the USART pins to communicate with a UART module just by using the RX and TX pins?

2) In the datasheet it mentions that the ATXMEGA has two USART modules. One on port C and one on port D. (image below). They are both labelled RXD0 and TXD0. Why are the functions named the same? These are still two unique and unconnected USART channels correct?

[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone confirm that I can use the USART pins to communicate with a UART module just by using the RX and TX pins?

This is correct, provided you configure the USART to operate in asynchronous mode (or *don't* configure it to operate in synchronous mode; it is a U*S*ART because it supports both modes).

> In the datasheet it mentions that the ATXMEGA has two USART modules. One on port C and one on port D. (image below). They are both labelled RXD0 and TXD0. Why are the functions named the same? These are still two unique and unconnected USART channels correct?

Correct. The ATxmegaXXA4U has *two* USARTs each on ports C and D, and each is designated "0" and "1", and all four (plus the fifth on port E) are completely independent (although they all behave identically).